# How to remove empty arrays from preg_split result?

Tags: php, regex, arrays

For an example I have tons of regex as simple I wrote:

```
php > var_dump( preg_split('/[:reg\s{}]+/', ':reg{/^[a-zA-Z]*$/}') );
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(0) ""
  [1] =>
  string(13) "/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"
  [2] =>
  string(0) ""
}
```

I want remove empty arrays `[0] => string(0) ""` for example a result should be:

```
php > var_dump( preg_split('????', ':reg{/^[a-zA-Z]*$/}') );
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(13) "/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"
}
```

I know `array_filter()` function when remove empty arrays, but I want using **regular expression only**.

Comment: Because I have a tons of regex which I'm writing, so I want to make a time shorter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`:

```
preg_split('/[:reg\s{}]+/', ':reg{/^[a-zA-Z]*$/}', -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

See the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: Okay, "-1" for no limit strings, and PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
If this flag is set, only non-empty pieces will be returned by. Thank you!