# How to trim line php?

Tags: php

I have the following function to split each line from file and group  it by columns count:

```
public function splitfile(Request $request)
{
    $groups = [];
    $session = Session::where('id', $request->id)->first();
    $file = Storage::get($session->filepath);

    $separator = "\r\n";
    $line = strtok($file, $separator);

    while ($line) {
        $line = strtok($separator);
        $splitted = explode("|", $line);
        $cols = count($splitted);
        $groups[$cols][] = $line;
    }

    return response()->json($groups);
}
```

As result I got array of arrays:

```
[24: [line1, line2...], 1: [false]]
```

Problem is here:  `1: [false]`. Probably it is empty line. How to trim it?

Comment: set the condition and if the line has data then insert into an array.

Comment: Did you get what I want, I want to split data by end of line, then each line split by separator

Comment: You said you want to trim the line which is empty. and it means you don't want to add the empty line to the array. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: So, just add if condition and add a line to in array only if line has the data

Comment: Maybe my approach is incorrect?

Comment: You could use `preg_split` and skip empties. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18702988/3783243 Assuming `$splitted = explode("|", $line);` is where the empties are coming in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the updated code will skip the lines which are empty.

```
public function splitfile(Request $request){
    $groups = [];
    $session = Session::where('id', $request->id)->first();
    $file = Storage::get($session->filepath);

    $separator = "\r\n";
    $line = strtok($file, $separator);

    while ($line) {
        $line = strtok($separator);
        if($line){
            $splitted = explode("|", $line);
            $cols = count($splitted);
            $groups[$cols][] = $line;
        }
    }
    return response()->json($groups);
}
```

May it helps :)